# Create a file listing that contains the created date of the file

Tags: iphone, file-listing, datecreated

I'm trying to copy photos from someone's iphone to my windows laptop. The problem is the photos on the iphone save as filename like IMG 360, IMG 361 etc... but this isn't helpful when I want to copy these and organise by a certain filename and date created.

I use Google Photos and my own backup to organise photos in chronological order.

We went on holiday together and I am trying to find the best way to get their files organised and merged in with my own photos so that they appear in the right chronological order.

Unless there is a better way to do this, I am trying to create a file listing using a BAT file to list all the files together with their CREATED DATE and then I will create another BAT file to rename those files by incorporating their CREATED DATE.

Any ideas?

Thanks Chirag

I tried the below but this is supposed to only organise in chronological order, but it doesn't seem to even do that.

dir /a /b /-p /s /T:C /o:gen >filelisting.txt

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. See [ask]. We need a [mcve]. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `dir /T:C /O:D > filelisting.txt` to create a file listing that contains the created date of each file in a directory.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to output the CREATION date in the txt file? The command you sent only orders the files by date, but I actually want to output the date in the output, ideally as a separate column. Thanks